# How to split multiple parts given paragraph

Tags: java

I want split given Paragraph

Basically I have to read meta Data

Having {no of Years exp} of experience in Analysis, Designing and Development of various [ Web based Applications and Platforms]   Working (experience in Java, JDBC, Servlets, JSP, GWT, Java Script, Struts)

out put should be like :

Having

no of Years exp

of experience in Analysis, Designing and Development of various

Web based Applications and Platforms

Working

experience in Java, JDBC, Servlets, JSP, GWT, Java Script, Struts.

Answer (score 0):

you have to define your requirement more clearly I am afraid. Given this specific input and output example, the easiest solution is to replace all the "special characters" - '{', '}', '(', ')', '[', ']' with line breaks '\n'

Comment: we can't replace spl characters , Special characters are to identify the data type like in that paragraph some static data and dynamic data and user data .. so based on the spl characters we have to separate data

Comment: What I meant was that the way to split your data is to copy the string and replace all the parenthesis with line breaks. After that, your data will be put into multiple lines where each line is a separate part